# IndexError: index out of bounds error using pandas .ix in a scipy function

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

In the following section of code, I continue to get an index out of bounds error and I can't for the life of me figure out why (none of the links on this site have helped me yet). What I want to do is apply my scipy curve_fit function (Func) to each row of data in x_data and y_data to get the a, b, c and d fit parameters. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import math

#my function
def Func(x_data,a,b,c,d):
    return np.multiply((np.multiply((a+cols), b)),
           (x_data.ix[i]/math.pi))+np.multiply((c+cols), d)

#create dummy dataframe
index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01','2017-03-01', freq='D')
columns=['1.234','2.345','3.456','4.567','5.678','6.789']

data1 = np.random.rand(60,6)
data2 = np.random.rand(60,6)

x_data=pd.DataFrame(data1, index=index, columns=columns)
y_data=pd.DataFrame(data2, index=index, columns=columns)

#values for function
cols=np.array(x_data.columns.values).astype(np.float)   

#Apply function to each row of x_data and y_data and append to empty array
data_popt=[]
data_perr=[]
for i, j in zip(range(0, len(x_data)), range(0, len(y_data))):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(Func,x_data.ix[i],y_data.ix[j])
    data_popt.append(popt)
    perr=np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
    data_perr.append(perr)
    index=x_data.index
    columns1=['a','b','c','d']
    columns2=['a_err','b_err','c_err','d_err']
data_popt=pd.DataFrame(data_popt, index=index, columns=columns1)
data_perr=pd.DataFrame(data_perr, index=index, columns=columns2)
```

P.s. I'm using python v 2.7.12 and pandas/scipy v 0.18.1

Comment: which line produces the error?

Comment: Whatever you're using to run your python script should be telling you exactly where the error is.  I deleted my previous comment because that wasn't the issue.  One thing I do notice is that you re-set your `index` within the loop to `x_data.index` which is redundant and is probably throwing off your last two lines of code where you're resetting the `index` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is produced on seventh iteration (`i=6`) in

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(Func,x_data.ix[i],y_data.ix[j])
```

in evaluation of `Func`

```
#my function
def Func(x_data,a,b,c,d):
    return np.multiply((np.multiply((a+cols), b)),
           (x_data.ix[i]/math.pi))+np.multiply((c+cols), d)
```

The problem is `x_data.ix[i]` since `x_data` passed to `Func` is `6x1` but `i=6`.

I guess you forgot that you are already passing a single row to `Func` and therefore you should not slice it further, i.e. define

```
#my function
def Func(x_data,a,b,c,d):
    return np.multiply((np.multiply((a+cols), b)),
           (x_data/math.pi))+np.multiply((c+cols), d)
```

---

Also trying to run this, sooner or later you will get `RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.` Therefore you need to increase `maxfev` i.e.

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(Func,x_data.ix[i],y_data.ix[j], maxfev=10000)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for providing such a useful and timely solution @matusko